# Select2 dropdown & model popup opens at the same time when click on select2 dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-modal, angularjs-select2

I have a requirement to open a confirmation box on click on select2 dropdown and when popup gets open, background page should be disable. I have done below coding but when I click on dropdown it open the popup but at the same time it also open own dropdown.please see the screen shot for visual effect

Below code written in HTML for select2 dropdown.

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedSectorModel.Selected" ng-click="ShowConfirm();" on-select="selectSectorEvents();" theme="select2">
    <ui-select-match>
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected.Text"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (industrySectorObject | filter: $select.search) track by item.Value">
        <span ng-bind="item.Text"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Below code written to open popup in controller.In controller i have written code for ShowConfirm();

```
$scope.ShowConfirm = function() { 
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'scripts/app/popup/myModalpopup.html',
        controller: 'MyCtrl',                    
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        resolve: {
            items: function() {
                return valueitem;
            }
        }
    });          
}
```

below code is for popup HTML myModalpopup.html.

```
<div class="container" style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Please Confirm</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Some Text Here
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button  class="btn btn-warning css3linear" type="button" ng-click="ok()" autofocus>OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning css3linear" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is Screenshot for the issue.
[background is disabled but not dropdown and also dropdown open on the top of popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt3Vj.jpg)

Comment: You are opening the popup box on the click event, so as expected the popup opens. What you need to do is change the popup open event to after the user has selected the option. So perhaps on the change event. Overall, this is bad UI design, you may want to reconsider having a popup there.

Comment: actually in my requirement i need to do something at on-select and also on-Click. so i had to use both. Can you suggest some code to close the dropdown when i open the popup. i am opening the popup through i method so if any code would be written in that method which is opening the popup, that will be great. please suggest something.